# What is the difference between double-quoting and not double-quoting an array in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, array, brace-expansion, shellcheck

While tracking down an error in my shellscript, I found the following behavior in this code snippet:

```
declare -a filelist
readarray filelist < <(ls -A)
readonly filelist
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  sha256sum ${filelist[$file]} | head -c 64
done
```

When the array `filelist` is not in double quotes, the command succeeds. I've been using ShellCheck to try to improve my coding, which recommends-

> Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

I'm not worried about word splitting in this case, but in a lot of other cases I am, so I'm trying to keep my code consistent. However, when I double quote the array, the command fails. Simplifying the code to a single element gives the following:

```
bash-5.0# sha256sum ${filelist[0]} | head -c 64
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

bash-5.0# sha256sum "${filelist[0]}" | head -c 64
sha256sum: can't open 'file1
': No such file or directory
```

I can obviously just... not double quote because in this instance word splitting isn't a concern. But I wanted to post because in the future it might be.

My question has two parts:

1. Is there a "best-practices" way to prevent word splitting other than double quoting the array as above?
2. <strike>Where are the single quotes coming from in the array?</strike>   Edit: there are no single quotes. The single quotes are the error showing the name of the file that cannot be opened.

Also, just out of curiosity, why does `echo ${filelist[0]}` not contain an additional newline but `echo "${filelist[0]}"` does?

Comment: The closest related question I found was [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518012/correctly-quote-array-that-is-being-passed-indirectly-via-another-command) but the solutions suggested involve not using Bash and not using arrays. I'm okay with Bourne solutions, but since I installed Bash specifically to use arrays, I'd like to know more about how it works before discarding it again.

Comment: `echo foo` will output a newline.  `echo -n foo` will not.

Comment: Related - [What is the difference having double quotes or not in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124631/100397)

Comment: Related - [$VAR vs ${VAR} and to quote or not to quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/100397)

Comment: I corrected my question to reflect that I don't understand why the quoted array creates an _additional_ newline. I'm asking why `echo ${foo[0]}` ends in **one** newline but `echo "${foo[0]}"` ends in **two** newlines. Providing that `echo -n ${foo[0]}` outputs **zero** newlines doesn't explain difference in the former two cases.

Comment: I think the first and foremost problem there is that you are [parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with quoting an array expansion.

And, of course, there is no problem with no quoting it either as long as you know and accept the consequences. Any non-quoted expansion is subject to splitting and globbing. And, in your code, the `${filelist[…]}` is subject to IFS character removal (and splitting if the string contains any `<space>`, `<tab>`, or `<newline>`).

That is what having the expansion un-quoted do, remove trailing `<newline>`.

What **creates** this problem is that you are using `readarray` without removing the trailing delimiter from each array element.
Doing that keeps a trailing `<newline>` that is reflected on the error message.

What you could have used is:

```
readarray -t filelist < <(ls -A)
```

The `-t` option will remove all the trailing newlines of each file name.

> -t     Remove a trailing delim (default newline) from each line read.

---

But your code has some additional issues.

- There is no need to declare or empty the array `filelist`. It gets done by default by readarray. It needs to be done in some other cases.
- There is no need to parse the output of `ls`, in fact, that is a bad idea. The easiest way to get a list of files in an array is simply:

  ```
  filelist=( ./* )
  ```

  And, to make it even better, it would be a good idea to avoid directories:

  ```
  for file in ./*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && filelist+=( "$file" )
  done
  ```
- In the loop, the value of the var `$file` is what should be used:

  ```
  for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    sha256sum "$file" | head -c 64
  done
  ```

  Unless you use `for file in "${!filelist[@]}"; do` which will list the **keys** of the array.
- The whole list could be processed with just **one** call to sha256sum:

  ```
  sha256sum "${filelist[@]}" | cut -c -64
  ```

The improved script is:

```
filelist=()              # declare filelist as an array and empty it.
for file in ./*; do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        filelist+=( "$file" )
    fi
done
declare -r filelist      # declare filelist as readonly.
sha256sum "${filelist[@]}" | cut -c -64
```

Answer (score 5):

> I'm not worried about word splitting in this case

Well, in fact, you're *relying on it* to remove the trailing newline from array entries!

[Bash's `readarray` (`mapfile`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) leaves the delimiters in by default. The man page or the command line help don't seem to say that explicitly, but there's an option to *remove* the delimiter, so by implication the default is that it's not removed:

```
-t     Remove a trailing delim (default newline) from each line read.
```

So, the actual string in the array is `file1[newline]`.

Without quotes, word splitting removes trailing whitespace, fixing the newline. But if you had filenames with spaces in them, word splitting would mess them up, as usual. Double quoting the array prevents that. To answer your first question, **the best practice is to double-quote**, here we just have an unwanted extra newline.

<sub>(Double quoting an array or `$@` is the slightly confusing exceptional case where a double-quoted string results in multiple words, one for each array element.)</sub>

You also have `${filelist[$file]}` in the `sha256sum` command line. That won't work, `file` already contains the value received from the array, not the index.

As a minimal modification, this might work:

```
declare -a filelist
readarray -t filelist < <(ls -A)
readonly filelist
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    sha256sum "$file" | head -c 64
done
```

(I don't think the explicit `declare` is actually necessary either.)

---

*The issue above has nothing to do with `ls` per se.* You'd get the same issue if you had filenames stored in a file, one per line, and used `readarray`/`mapfile` to read them without using the `-t` option. (Or if you read the output of `find`, but in that case, you might be able to use `find -exec` instead.)

Of course, this *is* a useless use of `ls` and some versions of `ls` might break your filenames on output. (I don't think GNU ls does that when outputting to a pipe.)

In Bash, you could instead fill the array with a glob:

```
shopt -s dotglob
filelist=(*)
for file in *; do ...
```

Or just run the loop on the glob without storing to an array:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for file in *; do ...
```

Note that you do need [`shopt -s dotglob` to get `*` to match dotfiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), and that's shell-dependant.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem based on your code snippet may be that you're parsing the output of `ls`.  This is dangerous and fraught with myriad issues and is best avoided.

Rather than

```
declare -a filelist
readarray filelist < <(ls -A)
readonly filelist
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
```

it is much simpler (and safer!) to:

```
for file in *; do
```

In this case:

```
for file in *; do
  sha256sum "${file}" | head -c 64
done
```

`readarray` as you are invoking it is also helpfully keeping the literal data passed into it, including the newlines.  So when you echo the quoted value, the newline is preserved.  when you do not quote it, the shell consumes it as intertoken whitespace to ignore.  This is also why `sha256sum` is failing.  If you have a file called `foo`, `readarray` is passing a value of `foo\n`, which does not correspond to a file.  Unquoting this "fixes" the problem by accidentally throwing out part of your variable's value.

Comment: Marked Isaac's answer as the solution because it directly answers the question I asked. Upvoted your answer because it answers the question I _should_ have asked, and I'll be refactoring accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Reasonable.  Glad to have been of assistance.